# When removing a specific element, it is returning 'null' for others

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to remove a specific movie from the array based on user input but the output is kind of wonky, all elements are supposed to be shifted up and I'm not sure what's wrong. output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wl4M.jpg

```
private static void listMovies() { 
    String[]movies = {"The Avengers","Rush Hour","Fast & Furious 7","The Ugly Truth","Spiderman"};
    
    for(int i=0; i<movies.length; i++) {
        System.out.println((i+1)+") "+movies[i]);
    }
}
private static void removeMovies (String[] movies) { 
    reenterUser(); 
    String[] deleteMovies = new String [movies.length-1]; 

    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Which movie would you like to delete?");
String movieDel = input.nextLine(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++){
        if (!movies[i].equals(movieDel)) {
            deleteMovies[i]=movies[i]; 
            i++; 
    }   
    System.out.println("You have deleted a movie!"); 

    System.out.println("This is an updated list of movies available at the rental store: ");
    printMoviesDeleted(deleteMovies); 
      
    }
private static void printMoviesDeleted(String[]movies) { 

    for (int i=0; i<movies.length;i++) { 
          System.out.println((i+1)+") " +movies[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the same index (`i`) for the new and old array. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: If there is only one movie (and you delete it) or if you delete all movies, then your `deletedMovies` definition is going to cause an exception  on the last movie's assignment. I recommend an `ArrayList<String>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Need a separate variable to specify the index in deleteMovies.

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++){
    if (!movies[i].equals(movieDel)) {
        deleteMovies[j]=movies[i];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got your delete function correct, but you're incrementing i twice in the delete for loop which is causing your strange output. You need to index the deletedMovies array with a separate index like this:

```
    private static void removeMovies (String[] movies) {
        reenterUser();
        String[] deleteMovies = new String [movies.length - 1];
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which movie would you like to delete?");
        String movieDel = input.nextLine();
   
     int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
            if (!movies[i].equals(movieDel)) {
                deleteMovies[j++] = movies[i];
            }
        }
            System.out.println("You have deleted a movie!");

            System.out.println("This is an updated list of movies available at the rental store: ");
            printMoviesDeleted(deleteMovies);

        }
```